# How To Export My Runnable Jar With Images And Sound?

Tags: java, image, jframe, inputstream, embedded-resource

I am making a basic program for my friend that shows this funny picture of him and loops a sound. When i export my JAR it didn't work so I opened the JAR with WinRar and the files were there but they weren't playing

**CODE:**

```
//imports
 public class twerk {
static File fl = new File("res//sounds//liver.au");
static int loo = 1;
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("COLLIN");
public static void frame(){
    frame.setSize(1086,800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("res//images//collin.jpg");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(image);
    frame.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    try
    {

        String st =fl.getPath();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(st);
        AudioStream au = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(au);
        if(loo == 1){
            Thread.sleep(1900);
            frame();
        }

    } catch(Exception e){}
}
    public static void main(String[] args){


    frame();

}

}
```

**A picture of the JAR file open in WinRar**

[image]

So you can see that the images and sounds folder are in the jar file, but they aren't being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time of deployment, those resources have become an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Note on paths.  According to that listing:

```
"res//images//collin.jpg"
```

Should become:

```
"/images/collin.jpg"
```